# c++ deserialize object sent from c# application via UDP

Tags: c#, c++, serialization, udp

I have an application in `c#` which connects to another application, written in `c++`, via UDP. I'd prefer a performant solution as I am looking to measure the time between an event client-side, some processing server-side and a response of processing complete back on the client-side. Essentially: Round trip delay.

I have an object in c#, for example:

```
public class Package{

    public Package(){}

    public float DeliveryTime = 1.5;
    public int NumberOfItems = 2

}
```

I then serialize my package to a byte array:

```
Package package = new Package();
var serializedPackage = ObjectToByteArray(package);
```

Next, I send my `serializedPackage` via UDP (I know, no guarantee of delivery or order, but I don't need those guarantees).

```
client.Send(serializedPackage , serializedPackage .Length, ip);
```

My c++ application then received the UDP message... 
the question is:

**How do I now convert my received byte array back into a usable object with property values maintained?**

I need to deserialize into some class Package c++ side and then use the properties... for example some sudo code:

```
DeserializedPackage deserializedPackage = someDeserializeFunction(bytes);
if(deserializedPackage.NumberOfItems > 0){
    cout << deserializedPackage.DeliveryTime;
}
```

Where do I start? Is this even possible?

I am well versed with C#, but absolutely new to c++, so no mixing c and c++, please. Also, I **do not** want to use `Boost` or another library.

I am also open to suggestions such as "convert your package object to JSON and send that. Then deserialize your JSON and populate a c++ object called package."

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the same, how to serialize types between two languages.

Protocol buffers are one way,  here is a similar question about what to do [between c++ and java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3986733/1734730). Google's PBs are suggested there,  although there are others.

However,  my favorite way to serialize objects in a language agnostic way is JSON. It's easy to reason with and probably the quickest cleanest thing you can implement. So I'd go with that first, unless you have any evidenced performance objection. You seem to already know how to do this?

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I know how to work with JSON. However, I'd prefer a performant solution as I am looking to measure the time between an event client-side, some processing server-side and a response of processing complete back on the client-side.